# Graph algorithm for propagating a feature

Tags: algorithms, graphs, machine-learning

I have the following problem:

> Given a graph of persons and their relationships.
> Suppose I have a classification of the risk of some of those persons.
> How can I calculate the classification of the others?

For instance, suppose I have a graph with 100 persons with the relations between each other (for example A is a friend of B (distance 2), C is the parent of D (distance 1)). And know suppose I know 20 of those persons has some risk from 0 to 1, let's say 0.9 for all 20. Is there any algorithm that can be used to classify the other 80? I know intuitively that if you have only one person of risk in your neighborhood then your risk should be lower than this neighbor, say like by 0.1. And I also know that the more you are involved with people with high risk, the higher your classification should be. I know this question doesn't have an objective answer but I'm open to any ideas of algorithms, I tried searching on the internet but didn't find any related to this topic. Does anyone know any algorithm or idea that might be useful in this case?

Comment: A lot of context seems missing.  What is meant by a "classification of the risk"?  How is risk of one person related to other people, and what relevance does the graph have to that?  Please formalize the problem in a precise way that doesn't require us to guess the answers to questions like that.  It is premature to ask for an algorithm to solve a problem if you can't formulate a precise problem statement.  I am concerned by your statement that this "doesn't have an objective answer" - I'm not sure whether this is a good fit for this site.

Comment: Have you looked into the PageRank algorithm?

Comment: I beleive this can be solved by graph-learning algorithms (a special version of machine learning which is used on graph-like data)